# How to disable default logging in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

In asp.net core 2.2 I could disable default logging with `ClearProviders` like in this code:

```
static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(config => {
                config.ClearProviders();
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

but I can't find `ClearProviders` in asp.net core 3.0
how can I do this in asp.net core 3.0?

Comment: Could you please clarify the issue? Are you getting an error, or what else is going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ClearProviders() is supported in ASP.NET Core 3.0 as per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggingbuilderextensions.clearproviders?view=aspnetcore-3.0#definition).
Maybe you miss `using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;` by any chance.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the IWebHostBuilder to IHostBuilder. Also Change WebHost to Host

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging((logging) =>
    {
        // clear default logging providers
        logging.ClearProviders();
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write this code in program.cs
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();